# Boosted Regression Trees prediction errors

Tags: r, regression, gbm

I am trying to run a Boosted Regression tree as I want to predict future scenarios for (G) but after I build the model and I try to actually predict my dependent variable (G) I get an error.

```
loyn<-read.csv("FullData.csv", strip.white=T, header=T, sep=',')
library(gbm)
head(loyn)

#G   Site         P        O      T Coral.Cover OCC  PPC
#1  23.023128 Lizard 27.494517 3.702791 25.470         4.2 8.2 20.9
#2  11.547282 Lizard 20.413183 3.664939 25.430         4.2 8.2 20.9

loyn.gbm<-gbm(G~Site+P+O+T+loyn$Coral.Cover+OCC+PPC, data=loyn, distribution="gaussian", train=0.75, interaction.depth=3, shrinkage=0.001, bag.fraction=0.5,cv.folds=3, n.minobsinnode=2, n.trees=10000)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
(best.iter<-gbm.perf(loyn.gbm, method="cv", overlay=T, oobag.curve=T))
summary(loyn.gbm, n.trees=best.iter)

# here I am asking what value G would have if Site=5, P=20, O=2.7, T=32, #loyn$Coral.Cover=4, OCC=2, PPC=20
new<-predict(loyn.gbm, newdata=data.frame(Site=5, P=20, O=2.7, T=32, loyn$Coral.Cover=4, OCC=2, PPC=20),n.trees=best.iter)
```

But it keeps saying

> Error: unexpected '=' in "new<-predict(loyn.gbm, newdata=data.frame(Site=5, P=20, O=2.7, T=32, loyn$Coral.Cover="

I have checked and it is not a typo. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try changing variable name `loyn.gbm` to `loyngbm`

Comment: Thanks so much! Unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: You need to change `loyn$Coral.Cover` to `Coral.Cover` in last line (i.e. `predict()`) as dataframe column's name can't have `$`